# Unity joystick input acting strange

Tags: unity, input, joystick

After setting up my joystick axes in Unity and sweeping them around I find that the Y-axis jumps to the opposite direction in certain positions.

So, when I press up on the joystick, the input will often indicate that it's pointing down. It will also sometimes do this in the opposite direction. It's somehow tied to the x-axis position, making it especially weird.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default Unity project settings include some joystick axes already. So looking further down, we find the same axis defined again!

Removing the extra axis definitions fixes the problem.

[image]